# Dividing two numbers in a list across a Pandas Series / Column

Tags: python, pandas

```
0    [1, 39]
1    [1, 39]
2    [1, 39]
3    [2, 39]
4    [4, 39]
```

So what I started with was a fraction in each row, I've got it split up into a list with numerical strings. I'd like to simply divide these and be left with a single float in each row. Where I'm at currently below:

```
t.apply(lambda x: float(t[0][0])/float(t[0][1]))

0    0.025641
1    0.025641
2    0.025641
3    0.025641
4    0.025641
```

It definitely feels like there's a better way to do this than using this method and looping through the whole dataset, but that's where I'm stumped! Another thing to consider is that there are NaNs throughout this column as well. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you to everyone who responded. The solution that ended up doing the trick was:

```
df ['INTRON'] = df['INTRON'].str.split('/').str[0].astype('float64') / df['INTRON'].str.split('/').str[1].astype('float64')
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `str`

```
df.str[0]/df.str[1]
Out[403]: 
0    0.025641
1    0.025641
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you start with following dataframe in the beginning:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'t':['1/39','1/39','1/39','2/39','4/39', np.NaN, '5/39']})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      t
0  1/39
1  1/39
2  1/39
3  2/39
4  4/39
5   NaN
6  5/39
```

Then, you want to split on `/` and there are `NaN` values in column. You may try following to create new column:

```
df['result'] = df.t.str.split('/').dropna().apply(lambda x: float(x[0])/float(x[1]))
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      t    result
0  1/39  0.025641
1  1/39  0.025641
2  1/39  0.025641
3  2/39  0.051282
4  4/39  0.102564
5   NaN       NaN
6  5/39  0.128205
```